# How to get the CPU usage consumed by APIs present under Chrome DevTools > Performance Monitor using Puppeteer

Tags: performance, google-chrome-devtools, puppeteer, performance-testing, browser-automation

How can I programmatically using Puppeteer to get the CPU usage data in real-time while performing UI clicks on the web page?

Need to get the CPU usage consumed by APIs which is present under Chrome DevTools > Performance Monitor using Puppeteer. Refer attached screenshot for reference.

[image: cpu usage under Performance Monitor]

I did some research, found the blog to get different performance metrics using Puppeteer but didn't found anything on how to capture CPU usage. - https://addyosmani.com/blog/puppeteer-recipes/

Also, found an open Github issue for the same, but still wanted to check on Stack Overflow if there is any solution or workaround to get CPU usage data using Puppeteer. - https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/6429